# Digitally Sign an Existing PDF in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, docusignapi

I wanted to sign a PDF programatically using NodeJS.I have changed the font family of signature field but my client is not satisfied with this.He wanted something whth which end user can do real signatures using mousepad.I dont know how to do this.I have seen some packages like PDF-Lib , node pdf-sign but there is no relative code/tutorial which I can use for it.

Here is my code :

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await readFile('pdf24_merged.pdf'));
        
        // Register font kit using fontkit imported on line 13
        pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
        
        // Using customFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes)
        const fontBytes = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'HouschkaW03BoldItalic.ttf'));
        const customFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes);

        // Using StandardFonts.TimesRomanBoldItalic
        const TimesRomanItalic = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.TimesRomanItalic);        
        

        const signature = form.getTextField('Datum und Unterschrift');
        signature.setFontSize(10);
        signature.setText(str);

        
        signature.updateAppearances(TimesRomanItalic);

        str = "";
```

I have tried using DocuSign API but unable to use it as I have no understanding of this.So if someone can help me out on how to do it?

Comment: If end-user using a mobile device- it will allow them to draw their signature on the phone/tablet

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign has functionality to allow signers to draw their signature.
It works better on mobile devices, but you can even do that on a desktop/laptop using your mouse. Just click this option here:

[image]